# JPanel display text progressively

Tags: swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have a Jpanel where i need to display a text taken from a file.
But i have to display the text word by word (one word per second). How can i do it?
I tried to override the paintComponent method but it can't display text progressively..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Timer (the one in the swing package). Assuming you have  the word-splitting part ready, the following pseudo-code snippet is an example of how to append them successively to a JTextArea:

```
 ActionListener l = new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(...) {
         textArea.append(words.remove(0));  
     }
 };
 Timer timer = new Timer(1000, l);
 timer.start();
```

If you really want to draw the String manually on a custom panel, let it have an append method and call that in your actionListener, something like

```
 class MyPanel .... 
    String text;
    public void append(String word) {
        text += word;
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(...) {
        super.paintComponent(..);
             // draw the string
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe are better methods , but in this case, make your own JPanel of course extending of JPanel, and override **public void paint(Graphics g)** , so you need a String with the entire text , another Array of String you can called myWords , other String called currentWords, finally a counter that is count the words you put

so you need to first fill the Array of Words , something like , this can be on the constructor, or when it reads the file

```
myWords = entireText.split(" ");
```

and then in the paint method, inside your timer when is 1 second you put

```
currentWords+= myWords[counter+1];
```

and finally you put

```
g.drawString(currentWords,0,0);
```

the last 0,0 , are X , Y coords, so maybe your will need to control this too, to put text in a new line

Comment: removed the downvote - the overall description is fine, just suggeting the wrong paint method. it's _not_ paint(...) it's paintComponent(..)